# Template part vs Sidebar (differences)

Tags: sidebar, footer, get-template-part

I want to add a hard coded footer into the... `footer.php` of my site. This doesn't need to be "dynamic" (adding and removing widgets), it will be something standard like info about the site and specific links.

If I am correct this can be done either by `get_template_part( 'template-parts/', 'infofooter' );`

or by `get_sidebar( 'infofooter' );`

In the second case I just have to name my file `sidebar-infofooter.php`

Are both methods equally valid? What is the difference between a (non-dynamic) sidebar and a template part? Is it that a sidebar usually includes widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get_sidebar($name);` function loads sidebar template file `sidebar-{$name}.php` if no name in the prentacies is specified it loads the `sidebar.php` file.

`get_sidebar()` and `get_template_part()` are almost identical, at the end they call [`locate_template()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) function that take care of loading from files.

The only difference is the hook fired. If you use `get_sidebar()` for all your widget areas you can target them all later with `get_sidebar` hook if needed.

So both options are equally valid in terms of code. They differ in semantics as sidebar usually contains a `dynamic_sidebar()` area inside the template.